# How can I change notification sounds on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, audio

When I get a notification, my phone has the standard "message received" sound for e.g. Twitter.

iOS 5 has sound settings for Text, Voicemail, Mail Received, Sent, and Tweet.

However, the Tweet sound seems to only apply to outgoing tweets, not received ones. In Notification Center settings, I can turn on "Sound" for each application, but is it possible to change the sound for app notifications globally, or better yet, per-application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not so far. You can do decide whether to turn on the sound or not for particular app (if it enables user to turn off the notification sound). But you cannot change the notification sound globally or per-app (not at least in iOS 5).

Comment: Are you 100% sure about this?

Comment: @Diago as your screen shot shows, there is no way to change the sound of notification excerpt twitter. And I think he was asking how to change the notification sound of other non-apple app, since you can change the sound of text message, mail and calendar in iOS 4.

Comment: Even then, changing the notification status in notification settings doesn't change the notification state inside the application itself. Even then, some applications, for example What's Up, does actually allow you to change the setting inside the application itself.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be what's happening: the "sound" setting is either on or off for each app, but I don't see any way to specify which sound.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the bigger changes in iOS 5. Under `Settings` -> `Sounds` you can change quite a few tones including Twitter, Mail and Sent Mail. It's not everything but the major one's are covered and a huge improvement from the previous versions.

They've also added a considerable amount of new tones, and you can now assign custom tones to all of them which previously didn't work.

[image: Sounds Settings in iOS5]

If you are referring to the notification beep you hear when you are inside the application itself, that will depend on each application if the developer has setup an option to change it. These aren't notifications as such, but rather built into the application and triggered by events inside the application.

Some applications, for example, What's App, will allow you to change the notification in it's own settings.

The short answer to this therefore is that it depends on the application, some can be globally controlled, and others need to have the ability enabled inside the application.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of these... I clarified my question: so what you're saying is that received tweets don't come through Notification Center, and the Twitter.app alone controls the sound?

Comment: Only default Apple applications use those sounds. 3rd party apps always use their own notification tones. The "tweet" tone is only applied to sending tweets through the native twitter system (say firing off a tweet through Safari). The tone is sounded when the tweet is sent, like the airplane "woosh" during an email. You cannot change 3rd party notification sounds unless they allow you to in the apps settings.

Answer (score 1):

## Finally — Yes, you can!

It's nearly 2024, but Apple has finally added a setting for the default alert sound in **iOS 17**.

[image]

No longer will you need to wonder, ***"was that my phone or yours"*** when a generic notification which does not have its own customizable sound occurs on your iPhone.

As the very date of this question shows, people have wanted this feature for years and years.  Finally, here it's here!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the alert sounds that came with that new app you just downloaded, they're actually pretty easy to change—and you don't even need to jailbreak your phone.
Unfortunately, this only works with non-Apple apps that use their own alert tones. If the app is using a tone that came with the iPhone (like Google Voice's app does), you'll need to be jailbroken to change it. Jailbreaking isn't that hard though. If you don't want to jailbreak, [here's how to change an alert tone.](https://lifehacker.com/5912464/how-to-customize-iphone-alert-sounds-in-third-party-apps-no-jailbreak-required)